# How can I add different stock labels

Tags: magento2, stock, stock-status

How can I add new stock labels to magento 2 so they appear in the product stock status select box ?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a custom module to solve your problem. And then you can create a plugin to add more stock option by do following steps:

> 1. app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/etc/di.xml

`<type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Source\Stock">
        <plugin name="training_source_stock" type="YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin\CatalogInventory\Model\Source\Stock"/>
    </type>`

> 2. app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/Plugin/CatalogInventory/Model/Source/Stock.php

```
class Stock
{
    const NEW_STOCK = 2;

    public function afterGetAllOptions(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Source\Stock $subject, $result)
    {
        $newStock = [
            [
                'value' => self::NEW_STOCK,
                'label' => __('New Stock')
            ]
        ];
        return array_merge($result, $newStock);
    }
}
```

> 3. Stock status will be show like this:

[image]

If this solves your issue, please give me a vote

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Lee, I will give it a go, that looks spot on :)

Comment: The code is good except that it does not save - on page reload the new stock option is either in or out of stock. - is stock status supposed to be boolean, in or out of stock ?